# how to make an application in android run even if the user destroyed it?

Tags: java, android, service

how to make an application\service in android run even if the user destroyed it?

I need that one class will work even if the user will close the application how can I do that?

Comment: you create a service and let it access some of the functions from some classes in your app, so to speak sharing functionality with service

Answer (score 1):

> how to make an application\service in android run even if the user distroied it?

If by "distroied" you mean the user force-stopped the application through the Settings application, your application will not run again until the user manually launches an activity of yours (e.g., through the home screen launcher), starting in Android 3.1.

If by "distroied" you mean the user killed the application using a "task killer", your application will not run again until the user manually launches an activity of yours (e.g., through the home screen launcher), at least through Android 2.1.

> I need that one class will work even if the user will close tha application how can I do that?

Redesign your application to not "need that one class will work even if the user will close tha application". Users are in control of their phones -- you are not.